# WPF - Radio button's bullet not align to the center of outer circle

Tags: wpf, radio-button

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEJX.png)

<Radiobutton Content="All" Height="14" Padding="0" FontSize="12" Margin="10,0,0,0" Ischecked={Binding isAll} />

Comment: Please add sufficient markup to reproduce your issue. What version of .net and os?

Comment: .Net 4.5.2 and windows 10

Comment: I used regular .net on my win 10 machine for the solution I posted. Which means your posted markup is not sufficient to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting VerticalContentAlignment="Center"

```
    <RadioButton  
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Content="All"  Padding="0" Height="14" FontSize="12"
```

Giving me:

[image]

You might want to also consider removing the Height="14" which will likely allow the text to line up with the circle.

Comment: No.. This is not working.. Adding that radio button is inside a grid row and binding is attached..  Vertical content alignment is added n styles.. Although (I feel) this does not have anything to do with this issue..